# collect function of Lisp in Clojure

Tags: clojure, lisp

I defined a function `is-prime?` in Clojure that returns if a number is prime or not, and I am trying to define a function `prime-seq` that returns all the prime numbers between two numbers`n` and `m`.

I have created the function in Common Lisp since I am more comfortable with it and I am trying to translate the code to Clojure. However, I cannot find how to replace the `collect` function in Lisp to Clojure.

This is my `prime-seq` function in Lisp:

```
 (defun prime-seq (i j) 
    (loop for x from i to j
                when (is-prime x)
                collect x
     )
 )
```

And this is the try I did in Clojure but it is not working:

```
 (defn prime-seq? [n m]
   (def list ())
   (loop [k n]
     (cond 
       (< k m) (if (prime? k) (def list (conj list k)))

     )
   )
   (println list)

 )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `collect` is not a function, it is a list accumulation clause provided by the `loop` macro.

Comment: @coredump Ah okay, thanks! But, how to replace it in that case in Clojure code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loop` in Clojure is not the same as CL `loop`. You probably want `for`:

```
(defn prime-seq [i j]
  (for [x (range i j)
        :when (is-prime x)]
    x))
```

Which is basically the same as saying:

```
(defn prime-seq [i j]
  (filter is-prime (range i j)))
```

which may be written using the `->>` macro for readability:

```
(defn prime-seq [i j]
  (->> (range i j)
       (filter is-prime)))
```

However, you might actually want a lazy-sequence of all prime numbers which you could write with something like this:

```
(defonce prime-seq
  (let [c (fn [m numbers] (filter #(-> % (mod m) (not= 0)) numbers))
        f (fn g [s]
            (when (seq s)
              (cons (first s)
                    (lazy-seq (g (c (first s) (next s)))))))]
    (f (iterate inc 2))))
```

The lazy sequence will cache the results of the previous calculation, and you can use things like `take-while` and `drop-while` to filter the sequence.

Also, you probably shouldn't be using `def` inside a function call like that. `def` is for defining a var, which is essentially global. Then using `def` to change that value completely destroys the var and replaces it with another var pointing to the new state. It's something that's allowed to enable iterative REPL based development and shouldn't really be used in that way. Var's are designed to isolate changes locally to a thread, and are used as containers for global things like functions and singletons in your system. If the algorithm you're writing needs a local mutable state you could use a transient or an atom, and define a reference to that using `let`, but it would be more idiomatic to use the sequence processing lib or maybe a transducer.

Loop works more like a tail recursive function:

```
(defn prime-seq [i j]
  (let [l (transient [])]
    (loop [k i]
      (when (< k j)
        (when (is-prime k)
          (conj! l k))
        (recur (inc k))))
    (persistent! l)))
```

But that should be considered strictly a performance optimisation. The decision to use transients shouldn't be taken lightly, and it's often best to start with a more functional algorithm, benchmark and optimise accordingly. Here is a way to write the same thing without the mutable state:

```
(defn prime-seq [i j]
  (loop [k i
         l []]
    (if (< k j) 
      (recur (inc k)
             (if (is-prime k)
               (conj l k)
               l))
      l)))
```

Comment: Note that you should never be using `conj!` for its side effects - you should always use the return value of `conj!` and similar operations on transients, since the effect on the passed in transient is not guaranteed, though it may be changed by the call it isn't always.

Comment: Yes, your version with transients is incorrect for the reason Joost Diepenmaat says. It should instead be written exactly the same as the final version, with the only change being that you use `conj!` instead of `conj`, and add the extra `transient` and `persistent!` calls at the edges of your algorithm. It's just as "functional" as the version without transients, and it performs better, so there's no reason to caution against it (except that, obviously, people often write incorrect code when dealing with transients!).

Answer (score 2):

I'd try to use [`for`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for):

```
(for [x (range n m) :when (is-prime? x)] x)
```

Comment: Similar: 

`(->> (range n m) (filter is-prime?))`